# showing xml String as formatted xml

Tags: java, xml, gwt

I have a xml string which is passed from the server to client side and I need to show the xml in  a dialog box. My xml response (which is actually a String) from the server looks something like this -

```
<docbody><name>somename</name><adr><state>NY</state><zip>1111</zip><street></street></adr></docbody>
```

I have a text area in the dialog box and i am using setText method to display the xml response. now the problem is, the xml is shown as plain text and my requirement is that, I want to display the xml exactly same way as it looks if we open a xml file in browser...I mean with all proper indentation and new lines for each tag.

Is ther any way to do this, on the client side of GWT. I have checked XMLParser, but it cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the text only string, that happens to be XML, to go through all the formatting that your browser does to XML documents.
First of all, this is browser dependent behavior, something that GWT is abstracting away from you, secondly, text areas don't support this kind of formatting.

You'd have to put it in an iframe or something and set all the meta information for the content appropriately.

Comment: Hmm... thats a good idea. Thanks. But something not needed for requirement(I mean use of iframes). but is definitely helpful for me in future.